# Name for limpers that call a pre-flop raise?

Tags: terminology

I've been watching some videos over at pokerstars.tv and the commentators have a name for limpers that call a later pre-flop raise. I think it was the name of the first (american?) tournament player that started to do that. Anybody kows what the name was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, found out! They refer to it as doing a "Gibbons"

Comment: I think a Gibbons is someone who limps early position with a big hand and then just calls a later raise. Close to the same thing, but it has to be a big hand.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this name, but in many broadcasts I heard the reporters calling those people "calling stations".

Comment: Calling stations are just people who always call and rarely fold or raise. Calling a pre-flop raise is called limping.

Comment: @ArtemIce: Calling the big blind preflop is called limping. However, the question for limpers, who also call a later preflop raise.

Answer (score 0):

Players can be classified as "Passive" or "Aggressive" based on the ratio of calls to bets & raises, and as "Tight" or "Loose" based on the proportion of hands they play (not including un-raised blinds)